# in react native how to request multiple urls in one action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to get data from three different URLs with only one action, how to achieve that. I have an action written like this.

```
export function listRepos(user) {
  return {
    type: GET_DATA,
    payload: {
      request: {
        url: `/users/${user}/repos`
      }
    }
  };
}
```

how to add axios.all that kind of promise to the action above to do three different get request in one action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using RxJs zip observable in your epic middleware

**Actions.js**

```
export function listRepos(user) {
   return {
           type: GET_DATA,
           payload:[
               request: {
                   url: `/users/${user}/repos`
                 },
               request:{
                   url:`second call`
                },
               request:{
                  url:`third call`
               }]
           }
 }
```

**epics**

```
 const cartSummary$ = (actions$, state) => {
      return actions$.ofType(Action.CART_SUMMARY)
         .flatMap(actions=> Observable.zip(
                  Api(actions.payload[0].request.url),
                  Api(actions.payload[1].request.url),
                  Api(actions.payload[2].request.url))
                     .map(data=> data[0],data[1],data[2])
                 )

    }
```

in data array you can access the data of individual apis